# C convert hex values "\xHH" to integer

Tags: c, formatting, hex, format-conversion

I want to convert a hex number from a file to an int.
The string looks like this:
`\0\0\x05\xa0`
This should be 1440. If I try:
`int i = '\x05'`
I get `5`.

But if I do the same with `\xa0` I get `-96`.
Any ideas how to convert the string correctly?

Comment: Is that an actual text string, or the data when viewed in a program that can display binary data?

Comment: Also, `-96` is the signed value of `0xa0`.

Comment: It is actually a PNG-header. I wrote an simple c program which can read the size out of an PNG-image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a [big-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) number.

Assuming you have the four (not 12 as if the bytes you showed are a string; I'm assuming they're binary bytes) bytes in an array of `unsigned char data[4]`, you should be able to convert like so:

```
const unsigned int x = (data[0] << 24) | (data[1] << 16) |
                       (data[2] << 8)  | data[3];
```

If we plug in your data:

```
const unsigned char data[] = { 0, 0, 0x5, 0xa0 };
```

the above becomes:

```
const unsigned int x = (0 << 24) | (0 << 16) | (5 << 8) | 160;
```

which is just `256 * 5 | 160` = `1280 | 160` = `1440`, just as expected.